# Trying to put my backgorund image in a Div element, but it's repeating

Tags: html, css, overflow, background-image

I'm trying to put my background image in a div element, but it's repeating vertically when I add the div, even with background-repeat: no-repeat; my inspect tool says I'm getting overflow. How would I stop this from happening?

```
<head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: rgb(21, 32, 43); 
        
    } 
           
    div {
        
        background-image: url("chewy.jpg");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;

        height: 200px;
        
    }
           
    </style>

    
</head>

<body>
 <div>
    stuff here
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Make a class

    <head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: rgb(21, 32, 43); 
        
    } 
           
    .header-box {
        
        background-image: url("chewy.jpg");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;

        height: 200px;
        
    }
           
    </style>

    
</head>

<body>
 <div class="header-box">
    stuff here
</div>

</body>
```

make a class maybe

.header-box {
        
        background-image: url("chewy.jpg");
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;

        height: 200px;
        
    }

Comment: So that did fix it. thank you, I'm still new to this so it was driving me crazy. Do you know why the div was making it repeat but giving it a class didn't?

Comment: Bro need to make class for anyone div or need to repeat class to div.

Comment: '.education {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 5rem;
}

.education .education-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 5rem;
}

.education-row .education-column {
    flex: 1 1 40rem;
}

.education-column .title {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin: 0 0 1.5rem 2rem;
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

.education-column .education-box {
    border-left: .2rem solid var(--main-color);
}
'